# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' - [ For when i try to login with username and password which are not exist. ]

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have written a login function that almost works except when I am trying to login with an invalid username and password it gives me an error. Which is:

> AttributeError at /account/login
>   'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

My login function:

```
def sign_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password =password)

        if User is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('addproducts')
        else:
            print("user not exist")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/login.html')
```

What I did wrong? Help me, please!

-Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
if User is not None
```

Should be

```
if user is not None
```

`User` is (probably) the `User` model/class so will never be `None`

Comment: It works fine. Thank You, good people. You guys are a superhero for me <3

Answer (score 0):

You get error `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'`, because authenticated can't get user which exist in database.

Comment: Yeah. I totally got it. Thanks

Comment: I got this error, when I make my user is_active = False, How can I solve this?